# R: Create category column reflecting match between a dictionary and column in df

Tags: r

I have a df with column content, and a dictionary with columns "animal","nature". df and dictionary have different amounts of rows.

**Df$content is ~30,000 rows; animal dict has 300,000 rows and nature dict has 600,000 rows - they are quite large. str_detect has been taking forever to load; looking for a solution that is applicable to large dfs**

I want to create a new column in df, "content_category" to reflect the animal/nature of each row in content based on match with any terms in the animal/nature dictionary, along with two binary columns "content_animal" and "content_nature" reflecting whether they were matched with animal or nature.

Df:

```
df<-structure(list(content = c("hello turkey feet blah blah blah", "i love rabbits haha", 
"omg did u see the rainbow?!", "wow this sunlight is amazing", "i love running across grassy lawns with my dog", "turtles like swimming in the water"), row.names = c(NA, -7L), class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame")))
df<-as.data.frame(df)
```

dictionary:

```
animal<-structure(list(animal = c("turkey", "turtle", 
"rabbit", "dog", "bear", "cat"), row.names = c(NA, -6L), class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame")))
animal<-as.data.frame(animal)

nature<-structure(list(nature = c("sunlight", "water", "rainbow", "grass", "lawn", "mountain", "ice", "sea"), row.names = c(NA, -7L), class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame")))
nature<-as.data.frame(nature)
```

desired result in df:

```
content_category: animal, animal, nature, nature, animal/nature, animal/nature
content_animal: 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1
content_nature: 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1
```

I've been trying to use dplyr's mutate(case_when) function to give me the output i want, but keep running into errors bc df and dictionary are not the same dataset. **Is there any simple or smart way to do this?**

I can only think of subsetting all df$content matching animal and nature, and then manually creating a binary variable=1 for each subset, and then leftjoining the new binary variables from the subsets back into my dataset by content. But this process is too long for such a simple conditional and has many problems, and would not generate the "content_category" i want.

I've been struggling with this for a while now, any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Regex to identify string patterns would do this well, either with `grepl` in base or in `str_detect` in the `stringr` package.

Comment: Can you please share your data in valid R syntax? For example, is `dictionary` a data frame? Or a `list`? Maybe something like `dictionary <- list(animal = c("turkey", "rabbit"), nature = c("sunlight", "water"))`? And similarly, please share `df` in valid syntax so we don't have to re-type it or write custom code to import what you've shared. If you have an existing data frame, `dput(df[1:10, ])` will share the first 10 rows in valid R syntax, preserving all class an structure information. Please post something like that.

Comment: @GregorThomas Apologies, i'll edit the OG post.

Comment: Your dput of the dataframe (`Df`) along with dictionaries is missing something. It returns a list.

Comment: @RonakShah df<-as.data.frame(df) should fix it.

Comment: @hongpastry Please update your post with the fix so that anybody can copy and use it. Not everybody will read your comment below the original post. Your `dput` is also missing a closing bracket. Double check your post and data before posting here. Make it easier for people who are trying to help you.

Comment: @RonakShah okay, fixing it in the OG post now, thank you for pointing that out and for helping!!~

Comment: @RonakShah fixed, this should work now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's unclear how the dictionary is input, I'm assuming it's separate vectors. Then, for each element of `df$content`, we simply need to run `str_detect()` and see if there was any match.

```r
library(tidyverse)
df <- tibble(content= c("hello turkey feet blah blah blah", "i love rabbits haha", "wow this sunlight is amazing", "omg did u see the rainbow?!", "turtles like swimming in the water", "i love running across grassy lawns with my dog"))

animal=c("turkey", "rabbit", "turtle", "dog", "cat", "bear")
nature=c("sunlight", "water", "rainbow", "grass", "lawn", "mountain", "ice")

df %>%
  mutate(content_animal = 1L*map_lgl(content, ~any(str_detect(.x, animal))),
         content_nature = 1L*map_lgl(content, ~any(str_detect(.x, nature))))
#> # A tibble: 6 x 3
#>   content                                        content_animal content_nature
#>   <chr>                                                   <int>          <int>
#> 1 hello turkey feet blah blah blah                            1              0
#> 2 i love rabbits haha                                         1              0
#> 3 wow this sunlight is amazing                                0              1
#> 4 omg did u see the rainbow?!                                 0              1
#> 5 turtles like swimming in the water                          1              1
#> 6 i love running across grassy lawns with my dog              1              1
```

<sup>Created on 2020-12-09 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

EDIT: If performance is an issue, you might get a faster solution by using a `fixed()` pattern in `str_detect()`. However that could create trouble if there are non-english characters in the text, it might be necessary to experiment.

```r
# bigger datasets
df <- tibble(content = sentences)

animal <- words[1:500]
nature <- words[501:980]

bench::mark(basic = mutate(df, content_animal = 1L*map_lgl(content, ~any(str_detect(.x, animal))),
                           content_nature = 1L*map_lgl(content, ~any(str_detect(.x, nature)))),
            fixed = mutate(df, content_animal = 1L*map_lgl(content, ~any(str_detect(.x, fixed(animal)))),
                           content_nature = 1L*map_lgl(content, ~any(str_detect(.x, fixed(nature))))))
#> Warning: Some expressions had a GC in every iteration; so filtering is disabled.
# A tibble: 2 x 13
#>  expression      min   median `itr/sec` mem_alloc `gc/sec` n_itr  n_gc total_time
#>  <bch:expr> <bch:tm> <bch:tm>     <dbl> <bch:byt>    <dbl> <int> <dbl>   <bch:tm>
#> 1 basic         5.24s    5.24s     0.191    2.77MB        0     1     0      5.24s
#> 2 fixed      261.63ms 266.19ms     3.76     8.22MB        0     2     0   532.38ms
# ... with 4 more variables: result <list>, memory <list>, time <list>, gc <list>
```

EDIT2:
To count the number of observations, since `str_detect()` returns a logical vector you can simply use `sum()` instead of `any()`:

```r
df %>%
  mutate(content_animal = 1L*map_int(content, ~sum(str_detect(.x, animal))),
         content_nature = 1L*map_int(content, ~sum(str_detect(.x, nature))))
#> # A tibble: 6 x 3
#>   content                                        content_animal content_nature
#>   <chr>                                                   <int>          <int>
#> 1 hello turkey feet blah blah blah                            1              0
#> 2 i love rabbits haha                                         1              0
#> 3 wow this sunlight is amazing                                0              1
#> 4 omg did u see the rainbow?!                                 0              1
#> 5 turtles like swimming in the water                          1              1
#> 6 i love running across grassy lawns with my dog              1              2
```

<sup>Created on 2021-02-12 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Comment: Hi, I tried the code but am running across the error: "Error: Problem with `mutate()` input `content_animal`. x no applicable method for 'type' applied to an object of class "c('tbl_df', 'tbl', 'data.frame')" ℹ Input `content_animal` is `1L * map_lgl(content, ~any(str_detect(.x, animal)))`."?

Comment: If the dict is separate data frames (as I think it is in your `dput()`, that's not totally clear), you need to call the columns: `df %>%
  mutate(content_animal = 1L*map_lgl(content, ~any(str_detect(.x, animal$animal))),
         content_nature = 1L*map_lgl(content, ~any(str_detect(.x, nature$nature))))`

Comment: Hi thanks for your help! I tried this, but it's taking a very long time to load (my dataset and dictionary are bigger than the dummy I put in the OG post above). Is there a way to make it speedier? I heard stringr str_detect is supposed to be really fast, so not sure why this is happening.

Comment: okay, thanks, trying it right now. It's still taking pretty long to load, I'll give it another hour and if it still doesn't load then, might have to try a different strategy.

Comment: Hi, is there a way to create the output so that it is not binary, but instead counts the number of matches each row has?

Comment: see edit #2, using sum instead of any, and changing the map to match the output

Comment: Thanks for all your help! Really appreciate it.

Comment: Hello, Is there a way to count the number of matches each row has, including repeated matches (for example "apple" appears 3 times, banana appears 1 time and the count of matches for this row is=4)? Right now the count only counts each match with unique words in each row (so if "apple" appears 3 times and banana appears 1 time, the count of matches for this row is only=2). Appreciate your advice.

Comment: Should be possible with [`str_count()`](https://stringr.tidyverse.org/reference/str_count.html) instead of `str_detect()`.